# JavaScript working is not working from application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to blur on mouse wheel on numeric fields so that it may not accidentally change with scroll.
the javascrpit function I 'm using is

```
$(function(){
  $(':input[type=number]').on('mousewheel',function(e){ $(this).blur(); });
});
```

It works fine when I write it in respective page e.g `index.slim`

but when I write it in application.js it doesn't work.

Whats the issue

Comment: $(document).on('page:change', function () {

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss it didn't work actually on click for new_button a page like pop up is opened instead of page load. method for new is like def new
    # hole.lengths.build()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

Comment: ok if you are saying a pop up or a modal opens i think know the problem. your function maybe is triggering in the background -- if you have another input[type-number] in the background? so you have to give this input[type-number] another attribute to separate it from the other. check your source code.

Comment: let me know if that is it and i will add it as an answer

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss
I didn't get this "if you have another input[type-number] in the background? so you have to give this input[type-number] another attribute to separate it from the other" can you explain it further

Comment: for example if you have a page open that has an element  `input[type=number]`  and you click a modal or a pop up that appears above that page and that modal or popup also has an element `input[type=number]`, your script will only be called on the first `input[type=number]` not on the modal/pop up `input[type=number]`.

Comment: ok
any solution  for this

Comment: yeah you need to find a way to change the element that the function is being called on. one way is to add a parent element. for example, you can call the function on `$(form#photo>:input[type=number]').on('mousewheel'...`

Comment: Did this work? Should I enter as an answer?

Comment: actually there are five forms in which I need the JavaScript function, thats why I wanted to write in application.js 
$(form#photo>:input[type=number]').on('mousewheel'... cannot work in such case.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: it didn't work actually on click for new_button a page like pop up is opened instead of page load. method for new is like def new
    # hole.lengths.build()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end